# How can I generate nice slides from markdown?

Tags: html, pdf, slideshow, markdown

I'd like to a write markdown code and then generate html and/or pdf slide decks. The simpler the better.

What options are available?

Comment: The original Markdown is [designed to be converted to HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), and there must be tons of existing solutions. Pick the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://remarkjs.com/?

I have found it pretty easy to use and is compatible with most markdown flavors.